# Drupal Module for displaying external websites

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am trying to write a new module for existing drupal,
I am stuck btw using file_get_content() and curl

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is a Q&A site where you ask when you get stuck. If you don't know where to start, please read https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to show external URL contents. Use html's iframe.

OR

use drupal_http_request()

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes it is working if i use iframe, but as I am restricted not to use iframe. all we have is a ibm api connect developer portal, where can i use drupal_http_request()

Comment: Instead of file_get_contents(), use: drupal_http_request().https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7.x